# Don't close MyApp

Tags: android, crash

I made an App called MyApp to android that lists in a ListView the Apps that are installed in my device. When i click at a line in my ListView it opens the App that is pointed by this line.

If this App that was opened by my MyApp crashes, it closes MyApp and goes to the home screen.

Is there any way to prevent this from happening?  I mean, if Apps opened by MyApp crashes, it will just crash and come back to MyApp, they will not crash and go to the homescreen.

Comment: Make MyApp be the home screen.

Comment: What is the logcat output when this happens?

Comment: "Unable to start activity ComponentInfo" , those Apps that crashes are meant to crash, they just start and Android says "[Appname] stoped" and you press "OK" and they are closed. And how can i make MyApp become the home screen?

Answer (score 0):

*Edited:*
based on comment indicating `java.lang.RuntimeException`: "Unable to start activity ComponentInfo"

---

In your example, your `ListView` app is called `MyApp` while the app being launched is called `App`.

In all cases, if `App` crashes, execution will return to `MyApp`. Therefore, the crash is occurring in your launcher `MyApp`.

In order to stop your app from crashing, wrap the `startActivity()` or `startActivityForResult()` call in a `try/catch` block.

Then, the `MyApp` Activity will remain visible after any application fails to launch.
Additionally, you have to opportunity to display a `Dialog` or `Toast` message in the `catch()` block to notify the user of the error.

Comment: Tried that and didn't work. I'm almost sure its the App that crashes and not MyApp, because android mentions the package that stoped working, and the package isnt from MyApp, but from the App.